# Returning the last computed result in a throttled function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, memoization, throttling

I am working on a exercise based of the [underscore _.throttle](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle) function. Our function is slightly modified as we have the return the last computed result if the `_.throttle` function is still waiting to execute the next call. I've managed to make the throttle functionality work, however computing the last result hasn't been successful for me.

### What I've tried

I've worked on a memoization function before the throttle function, and I thought that it would be a smart idea to combine both. I've tried multiple different ways of implementing the memoization code in the `_.throttle` function, but my tests keep failing. Here are 2 of my attempts:

```js
_.throttle = function (func, wait) {
  let throttle = false;
  let cache = {};

  return function (...arguments) {
    const key = JSON.stringify(arguments);
    let result = func.apply(this, arguments);
    cache[key] = result;

    if (!throttle) {
      throttle = true;

      setTimeout(function () {
        throttle = false;
      }, wait);

      return result;
    } else {
      return cache[key];
    }
  };
};
```

```js
_.throttle = function (func, wait) {
  let throttle = false;
  let cache = {};

  return function (...arguments) {
    const key = JSON.stringify(arguments);

    if (throttle) {
      return cache[key];
    }

    let result = func.apply(this, arguments);
    cache[key] = result;
    throttle = true;

    console.log(cache[key]);


    setTimeout(function () {
      throttle = false;
    }, wait);

    return result;
  };
};
```

### What I am looking for

Basically, I want to return the last computed result if the `setTimeout` hasn't finished yet. The function that is passed through the `_.throttle` reverses a string that is passed through its arguments. I have tried several variations of the above code to find out if the `return cache[key]` is not in the wrong spot and therefore getting the wrong value, but I can't find a location where it works. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually underscore does already provide everything the OP needs ... [`_.throttle`](https://underscorejs.org/docs/modules/throttle.html) via its 3rd optional `options` parameter allows a very specific invocation handling for the leading and trailing edge invocations, and [`_.memoize`](https://underscorejs.org/?#memoize) is implemented as well. Thus there seems to be no reason for inventing something oneself since a function with the OP's specifically modified behavior easily can be created like e.g. ... `const fct = _.throttle(_.memoize(toBeMemoizedAndThrottledFct), 200)`.

Comment: `_.throttle` does what is asked out of the box, no need to play with the options or `_.memoize`. See the `return result` line in the source code: https://underscorejs.org/docs/modules/throttle.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do exactly what I wanted, without memoization. Turns out you only need to initialise the result before, then save result. Here is the code how I managed to pass my tests:

```js
_.throttle = function (func, wait) {
  let throttle = false;
  let result;

  return function (...arguments) {
    if (throttle) {
      return result;
    }

    result = func.apply(this, arguments);
    throttle = true;

    setTimeout(function () {
      throttle = false;
    }, wait);

    return result;
  };
};
```

The above program returns a throttled function. When there are many subsequent calls, the calls will simply return the last computed result! This optimizes the speed of your program.

Comment: And how does the OP manage to act upon the last returned result as well as on every other returned result and how to tell them apart?